# Unreal Engine 4.21.2 & Squareys CISQLite3 Plugin Compile Issues

Tags: c++, plugins, sqlite, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4

I am attempting to integrate SQLite3 into my test project in UE4 but I am running into some, no a lot of problems.

First some housekeeping.  Link to the repo on GitHub where Square has the plugin which is a forked and updated version of the old CISQLite3 plugin:

https://github.com/Squareys/unreal-sqlite3

Next, the project I am using is a Blueprint project with custom classes created from within the editor.

Installation Steps:
I followed the install guide in the readme on the repo which states the following:

Download the plugin zip and extract it into your project Plugins folder.  Open the editor and go to the Plugin Manager and enable the plugin.  Restart and allow the editor to compile the plugin.

In 4.20.x this was apparently all that was needed.  For whatever reason in 4.21.2 this process is broken.  I am getting all kinds of issues relating to the generated files.

So for what I have tried:
I have tried giving the absolute path for the generated files in the plugin intermediate folder - this just allows the compiler to spew errors forth like an Old Faithful from hell.

I have tried starting a fresh project; three times.  I always hit a point where I can't go any further because of an error I will put later in the post.

I have tried regenerating the project files after removing the .vs, binaries, intermediate, and saved folders.  Sometimes the rebuild works to recreate the files (does not fix the problems) but at some point it starts failing and when I open the project it will fail to compile the project dll/lib and says to compile manually.

Okay, so on to the actual errors.  I am going to walk you through step by step and display the errors at each step of debugging that I do.

So first and foremost, even in a new project with no custom code, I get these two warnings:

> MiningTechDemo5\Plugins\CISQLite3\Source\CISQLite3\CISQLite3.Build.cs: warning: Modules must specify an explicit precompiled header (eg. PrivatePCHHeaderFile = "Private/CISQLite3PrivatePCH.h") from UE 4.21 onwards.
>
> MiningTechDemo5\Plugins\CISQLite3\Source\CISQLite3\CISQLite3.Build.cs: warning: Referenced directory 'F:\UE4\Epic Games\UE_4.21\Engine\Source\CISQLite3\Public' does not exist.

To fix this I changed the plugin build file to this:

```
// Copyright (c) 2015 Jussi Saarivirta 2016 conflict.industries MIT License (MIT)

using UnrealBuildTool;

public class CISQLite3 : ModuleRules
{
  public CISQLite3(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
  {

    PublicIncludePaths.AddRange(
      new string[] {
        "F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Source/CISQLite3/Public"
      }
    );

    PrivateIncludePaths.AddRange(
      new string[] {
        "F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Source/CISQLite3/Private"
      }
    );

    PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(
      new string[] {
        "Engine",
        "Core",
        "CoreUObject"
      }
    );

    PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(
      new string[] {}
    );

    DynamicallyLoadedModuleNames.AddRange(
      new string[] {}
    );
  }
}
```

I have to use absolute paths because for some reason ModuleDirectory just points to my F:\ drive and not the project/plugin folder.  So, those errors are gone now.  Everything seems fine until I go to include SQLiteDatabase.h into my DatabaseHandler custom class (created in the editor).

The first error I get is that DatabaseHandler.generated.h cannot be found but that is because of a second error that SQLiteDatabase.h cannot be found.  So I think, maybe this is the same issue as with the CISQLite3 build file and I change my project build file from the default generated code to this:

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

using UnrealBuildTool;

public class MiningTechDemo5 : ModuleRules
{
    public MiningTechDemo5(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
    {
        PCHUsage = PCHUsageMode.UseExplicitOrSharedPCHs;
    
        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Core", "CoreUObject", "Engine", "InputCore" });

        PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] {  });

        PrivateIncludePaths.Add("F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Source/CISQLite3/Private");
        PublicIncludePaths.Add("F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Source/CISQLite3/Public");
        PublicLibraryPaths.Add("F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Binaries/Win64");

        // Uncomment if you are using Slate UI
        // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] { "Slate", "SlateCore" });
        
        // Uncomment if you are using online features
        // PrivateDependencyModuleNames.Add("OnlineSubsystem");

        // To include OnlineSubsystemSteam, add it to the plugins section in your uproject file with the Enabled attribute set to true
    }
}
```

Once again, full paths because ModuleDirectory is not working and Path.Combine does not work either; at least not with string properties that return parts of the path as helper members so there is less text being typed.

So I rebuild, same error.  I go ahead and change the include to an absolute path from this:

> ## include "SQLiteDatabase.h"

To this:

> ## include "F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Source/CISQLite3/Public/SQLiteDatabase.h"

Recompile.  Huzzah, no error for that.  Crap, because now there is a new error.  This one is for the SQLiteBlueprintNodes.h file:

> Cannot open include file: 'SQLiteBlueprintNodes.generated.h': No such file or directory

Okay, so I absolute path it to this:

> ## include "F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/CISQLite3/SQLiteBlueprintNodes.generated.h"

It is at this point that the compiler takes the generated file and eviscerates it with a bunch of compiler barf and a new generated file not found error for SQLiteDatabaseStructs.generated.h:

```
'FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode' uses undefined struct 'CISQLITE3_API'   8

'friend': not allowed outside of a class definition 9
type 'Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode_Statics' unexpected   9

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    14

'FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'  14

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    15

'FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'  15

'FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode': constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions  16

syntax error: '}'   19

syntax error: missing ';' before '}'    19

'FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode' uses undefined struct 'CISQLITE3_API'    23

'friend': not allowed outside of a class definition 24

type 'Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode_Statics' unexpected    24

'FString Query': redefinition   27

'void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'Query''(void)': constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions   27

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    29

'FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'   29

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    30

'FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable'   30

'FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode': constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions   31

syntax error: '}'   34

syntax error: missing ';' before '}'    34

'FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery' uses undefined struct 'CISQLITE3_API'  38

'friend': not allowed outside of a class definition 39

type 'Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery_Statics' unexpected  39

'FString Query': redefinition   42

'void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'Query''(void)': constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions   42

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    44

'FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable' 44

missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    45

'FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery': redefinition; previous definition was 'data variable' 45

'FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery': constructor initializer lists are only allowed on constructor definitions 45

syntax error: '}'   46

syntax error: missing ';' before '}'    46

Cannot open include file: 'SQLiteDatabaseStructs.generated.h': No such file or directory    2
```

For every generated file that I absolute path, I get all of these same errors, and one additional generated file error until I get back to SQLiteDatabase.h.  When I absolute path the generated file this is the new error I get:

> Expected an include at the top of the header: '#include "SQLiteDatabase.generated.h"'

For brevity I will include all of the files mentioned above and their generated files, if they were throwing errors, below:

SQLiteBlueprintNotes.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/CISQLite3/SQLiteBlueprintNodes.generated.h"


USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Database Query")
    FString Query;

    FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode(){}
    FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode(FString LHSQuery, FString Append) : Query(LHSQuery)
    {
        Query += Append;
    }
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Database Query")
    FString Query;

    FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode(){}
    FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode(FString LHSQuery, FString Append) : Query(LHSQuery)
    {
        Query += Append;
    }
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Database Query")
    FString Query;

    FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery(){}
    FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery(FString Query) : Query(Query){}
};
```

SQLiteBlueprintNodes.generated.h:

```
// Copyright 1998-2018 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
/*===========================================================================
    Generated code exported from UnrealHeaderTool.
    DO NOT modify this manually! Edit the corresponding .h files instead!
===========================================================================*/

#include "UObject/ObjectMacros.h"
#include "UObject/ScriptMacros.h"

PRAGMA_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#ifdef CISQLITE3_SQLiteBlueprintNodes_generated_h
#error "SQLiteBlueprintNodes.generated.h already included, missing '#pragma once' in SQLiteBlueprintNodes.h"
#endif
#define CISQLITE3_SQLiteBlueprintNodes_generated_h

#define MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteBlueprintNodes_h_39_GENERATED_BODY \
    friend struct Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery_Statics; \
    static class UScriptStruct* StaticStruct();


#define MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteBlueprintNodes_h_24_GENERATED_BODY \
    friend struct Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteQueryTermExpectedNode_Statics; \
    static class UScriptStruct* StaticStruct();


#define MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteBlueprintNodes_h_9_GENERATED_BODY \
    friend struct Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteQueryLogicExpectedNode_Statics; \
    static class UScriptStruct* StaticStruct();


#undef CURRENT_FILE_ID
#define CURRENT_FILE_ID MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteBlueprintNodes_h


PRAGMA_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
```

SQLiteDatabaseStructs.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/CISQLite3/SQLiteDatabaseStructs.generated.h"

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteIndex
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** String with piece if SQL script*/
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Index")
        FString ResultStr = "";

    /** Index name*/
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Index")
        FString IndexName = "";

};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLitePrimaryKey
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** String with piece if SQL script*/
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Primary Key")
        FString ResultStr = "";
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteTableField
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** String with piece if SQL script*/
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table Field")
        FString ResultStr = "";

    /** Field name*/
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table Field")
        FString FieldName = "";

    /** Field type*/
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table Field")
        FString FieldType = "";

    /** Field value*/
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table Field")
        FString FieldValue = "";

};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteTableRowSimulator
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** Index name*/
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Index")
        TArray<FSQLiteTableField> rowsOfFields;

};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteTable
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** Database name*/
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table")
        FString DatabaseName = "";

    /** Table name*/
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table")
        FString TableName = "";

    /** Array with Fields*/
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table")
        TArray<FSQLiteTableField> Fields;

    /** Primary Key */
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table")
        FSQLitePrimaryKey PK;

    /** Created Key */
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Table")
        bool Created = false;

};
```

SQLiteDatabaseStructs.generated.h:

```
// Copyright 1998-2018 Epic Games, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
/*===========================================================================
    Generated code exported from UnrealHeaderTool.
    DO NOT modify this manually! Edit the corresponding .h files instead!
===========================================================================*/

#include "UObject/ObjectMacros.h"
#include "UObject/ScriptMacros.h"

PRAGMA_DISABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#ifdef CISQLITE3_SQLiteDatabaseStructs_generated_h
#error "SQLiteDatabaseStructs.generated.h already included, missing '#pragma once' in SQLiteDatabaseStructs.h"
#endif
#define CISQLITE3_SQLiteDatabaseStructs_generated_h

#define MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteDatabaseStructs_h_66_GENERATED_BODY \
    friend struct Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteTable_Statics; \
    static class UScriptStruct* StaticStruct();


#define MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteDatabaseStructs_h_55_GENERATED_BODY \
    friend struct Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteTableRowSimulator_Statics; \
    static class UScriptStruct* StaticStruct();


#define MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteDatabaseStructs_h_32_GENERATED_BODY \
    friend struct Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteTableField_Statics; \
    static class UScriptStruct* StaticStruct();


#define MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteDatabaseStructs_h_22_GENERATED_BODY \
    friend struct Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLitePrimaryKey_Statics; \
    static class UScriptStruct* StaticStruct();


#define MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteDatabaseStructs_h_7_GENERATED_BODY \
    friend struct Z_Construct_UScriptStruct_FSQLiteIndex_Statics; \
    static class UScriptStruct* StaticStruct();


#undef CURRENT_FILE_ID
#define CURRENT_FILE_ID MiningTechDemo5_Plugins_CISQLite3_Source_CISQLite3_Public_SQLiteDatabaseStructs_h


PRAGMA_ENABLE_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
```

SQLiteDatabase.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "sqlite3.h"
#include "SQLiteBlueprintNodes.h"
#include "SQLiteDatabaseStructs.h"
#include "F:/UE4/Projects/MiningTechDemo5/Plugins/CISQLite3/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/CISQLite3/SQLiteDatabase.generated.h"

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteDatabaseReference
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** The database name (not the filename) */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Database Reference")
        FString DatabaseName;

    /** The database tables we want to get data from */
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Database Reference")
        TArray<FString> Tables;
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteKeyValuePair
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** The database table field name */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Key Value Pair")
        FString Key;

    /** The value of the field */
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Key Value Pair")
        FString Value;
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteQueryResultRow
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** A list of field name, field value pairs */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Query Result")
        TArray<FSQLiteKeyValuePair> Fields;
};

USTRUCT(BlueprintType)
struct CISQLITE3_API FSQLiteQueryResult
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

        /** The resulting rows from the query */
        UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BlueprintReadWrite, Category = "SQLite Query Result")
        TArray<FSQLiteQueryResultRow> ResultRows;

    /** Was the query successful or not */
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "SQLite Query Result")
        bool Success;

    /** If the query was unsuccessful a human readable error message will be populated here */
    UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, Category = "SQLite Query Result")
        FString ErrorMessage;

};



// A few things for internal use here.
namespace SQLiteResultValueTypes
{
    enum SQLiteResultValType
    {
        Integer,
        Float,
        Text,
        UnsupportedValueType
    };
}

// Result field, used as an intermediary when collecting results from
// an SQLITE3 query.
struct SQLiteResultField
{
    FString StringValue;
    double DoubleValue;
    int64 IntValue;

    FString Name;
    SQLiteResultValueTypes::SQLiteResultValType Type;

    FString ToString()
    {
        if (Type == SQLiteResultValueTypes::Text)
            return StringValue;
        else if (Type == SQLiteResultValueTypes::Integer)
            return FString::Printf(TEXT("%i"), IntValue);
        else if (Type == SQLiteResultValueTypes::Float)
            return FString::Printf(TEXT("%f"), DoubleValue);

        return StringValue;
    }
};

// Represents a single row in the result.
struct SQLiteResultValue
{
    TArray<SQLiteResultField> Fields;
};

// The internal result object.
struct SQLiteQueryResult
{
    bool Success;
    FString ErrorMessage;
    TArray<SQLiteResultValue> Results;
};



/**
* SQLite main database class.
*/
UCLASS()
class CISQLITE3_API USQLiteDatabase : public UObject
{
    GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()

public:
    /** Create a sqlite database file if it doesn't exist already. Does nothing if already exists.
    *   Returns false if the file couldn't be created */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite")
        static bool CreateDatabase(const FString& Filename, bool RelativeToGameContentDirectory);

    /** Checks if the database is registered, ie. that it can be found in Databases. */

    /** Add a database to the list of databases. It will be checked that it's valid (will try to open it) */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite")
        static bool RegisterDatabase(const FString& Name, const FString& Filename, bool RelativeToGameContentDirectory, bool KeepOpen=false);

    /** Remove a database from the list of databases. Closes the database in case KeepOpen flag was set during @ref RegisterDatabase */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite")
        static void UnregisterDatabase(const FString& Name);

    /** Checks if the database is registered, ie. that it can be found in Databases. */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite")
        static bool IsDatabaseRegistered(const FString& DatabaseName);

    /** Get data from the database using a select statement straight into an UObject, ie. populates its properties. */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite", meta = (DisplayName = "Get Data Into Object (manual query)"))
        static bool GetDataIntoObject(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& Query, UObject* ObjectToPopulate);

    /** Blueprint: Gets data from the database using a select statement straight into an UObject, ie. populates its properties.
    *   Note: Does not create a new object. ObjectToPopulate is the reference to the object you want to populate. */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite", meta = (DisplayName = "Get Data Into Object"))
        static bool GetDataIntoObjectBP(const FSQLiteDatabaseReference& DataSource, TArray<FString> Fields, FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery Query, UObject* ObjectToPopulate);

    /** Get data from the database using a select statement and return the rows. */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite", meta = (DisplayName = "Get Data From Table(s) (manual query)"))
        static FSQLiteQueryResult GetData(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& Query);

    /** Blueprint: Get data from the database. Returns the resulting rows. */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite", meta = (DisplayName = "Get Data From Table(s)"))
        static FSQLiteQueryResult GetDataBP(const FSQLiteDatabaseReference& DataSource, TArray<FString> Fields, FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery Query, int32 MaxResults = -1, int32 ResultOffset = 0);

    /** Create table in the database. */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Create Table"))
        static FSQLiteTable CreateTable(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& TableName,
        const TArray<FSQLiteTableField> Fields, const FSQLitePrimaryKey PK);

    /** Create indexes for table */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Create Indexes"))
        static bool CreateIndexes(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& TableName, const TArray<FSQLiteIndex> Indexes);

    /** Create index for table */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Create Index"))
        static bool CreateIndex(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& TableName, const FSQLiteIndex Index);

    /** Drop index*/
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Drop Index"))
        static bool DropIndex(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& IndexName);

    /** Drop Table*/
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Drop Table"))
        static bool DropTable(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& TableName);

    /** Truncate Table*/
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Truncate Table"))
        static bool TruncateTable(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& TableName);

    /** Is table exists?*/
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Is table exists?"))
        static bool IsTableExists(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& TableName);

    /** Insert rows into table */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Insert Rows Into Table"))
        static void InsertRowsIntoTable(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& TableName, TArray<FSQLiteTableRowSimulator> rowsOfFields);

    /** Compact database*/
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Compact database"))
        static bool Vacuum(const FString& DatabaseName);

    /** Execute SQL (can be used for insert statement)*/
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Execute SQL"))
        static bool ExecSql(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& Query);

    /** Checks database validity (if the file exists and/or if it can be opened). */
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "SQLite|Query", meta = (DisplayName = "Is Valid Database"))
        static bool IsValidDatabase(const FString& DatabaseFilename, bool TestByOpening);

    /** Runs a query and returns fetched rows. */
        static TUniquePtr<SQLiteQueryResult> RunQueryAndGetResults(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& Query);
private:
    /** Tries to open a database. */
    static bool CanOpenDatabase(const FString& DatabaseFilename);
    /** Collects all properties from an UObject and maps them by the property name. */
    static TMap<FString, UProperty*> CollectProperties(UObject* SourceObject);
    /** Constructs an SQL query from the blueprint fed data. */
    static FString ConstructQuery(TArray<FString> Tables, TArray<FString> Fields, FSQLiteQueryFinalizedQuery QueryObject, int32 MaxResults = -1, int32 ResultOffset = 0);
    /** Assigns a result row's fields' values to an UObject, ie. assigns them to the properties that have the same name. */
    static void AssignResultsToObjectProperties(const SQLiteResultValue& ResultValue, UObject* ObjectToPopulate);
    /** @brief Prepare given statement, returns whether to keep the database open */
    static bool PrepareStatement(const FString& DatabaseName, const FString& Query, sqlite3** Db, int32** SqlReturnCode,
        sqlite3_stmt** PreparedStatement);


private:
    /** A list of the databases for convenience, easier to refer to them by name rather than a long filename. */
    static TMap<FString, FString> Databases;

    static TMap<FString, sqlite3*> SQLite3Databases;

};
```

PasteBin for SQLiteDatabase.generated.h as it was too long to include in the question body:

https://pastebin.com/ZFsg9KEv

I am really out of ideas at this point and I cannot find anything online even similar to this with this plugin.  Not sure if anyone has been using it with more recent versions of the engine.  Any help will be greatly appreciated by myself and the wall next to my computer.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have managed to resolve this by just using the amalgamation directly into the source folder of a new project but I think the UE4 community will benefit as a whole if this can be figured out.  While there are some nice plugins for SQLite3 integration they cost a lot and if you don't need the bells and whistles they are not cost effective.